# How to access files across pages / R+RMarkdown+Hugo

Tags: r, web, r-markdown, relative-path, hugo

I am using RMarkdown+Hugo to create a website (eventually to go to netlify via github). I am stumped by how to handle file paths.

First, I have a navigation bar defined in config.yaml. One of the links in the navigation bar is to a .pdf file contained in `static/files/pdffolder/pdf1.pdf`. I define it as:

```
menu:
  primary:
.... 
    - identifier: pdf
      name: PDF
      url: files/pdffolder/pdf1.pdf
      weight: 2
- identifier: blog
  name: Blog
  url: /blog/ 
  weight: 3
```

(where I omitted some stuff where the ... is). When I preview the site in my web browser on the local host, the file works fine when I initially click on it.

But when I first go the the Blog link, and then click on the PDF link, it does not work because it tries to find it at `/blog/files/pdffolder/pdf1.pdf`, which of course does not exist. How can I modify things so that I always refer to `pdf1.pdf` no matter which page I am starting from?

Related - it also happens that RStudio renders a given image inline, but this image is not found in the web browser local host, and vice versa. Again, there seems to be an issue with relative file paths. How can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe you wanna use absolute paths starting with / for referencing files? They are independent no matter where you are currently.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried `/files/pdffolder/pdf1.pdf` and `static/files/pdffolder/pdf1.pdf` and `/static/files/pdffolder/pdf1.pdf` and each time the file was not found.

Comment: Actually, the / solution solved my problem. Thanks!